# Deploying config file from VSPackage?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vs-extensibility

I have a Visual Studio extension (CustomTool) that depends on NLog for logging. I'd like to deploy the NLog config file to the same directory that the tool's assembly gets installed to via the VSPackage.

I've looked at the Vsix manifest but can't seem to find a way to deploy such artifacts.

Is there a way to do so?

*Update:*

Apparently, if "Copy to Output" is set on a file on a project being referenced from the main VSIX project, it packages up the file. But this is not the case if the file is in the main VSIX project, even if "Copy to Output" has been set?! Any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the Build Action is set to "Content" and "Include in VSIX" is True.